# Typescript build error in vs2017

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, durandal

I have a DurandalJS project build using typescript v1.5 configured perfectly and working in Visual Studio 2013 with Typescript Tool v1.5 installed in it. Now I am trying to migrate the typescript in the project to the latest version v2.6 in VS 2017. I am encountering many build issues. Can any one provide me inputs on how to migrate the typescript 1.5 project and the related conifgurations to make it work with latest typescript version(2.6)  in visual studio ?

Comment: You're giving very little for us to work with. Show us the build issues you're getting, for a start. Also, Typescript did a lot of breaking changes in its 2.0 version. Build issues are to be expected.

Comment: Thanks for getting back @AksharPatel I have sorted it out. It was mainly due to the existing ts files which were not having proper static typing.